# Elliptic curve division polynomials equations calculations are not matching

Tags: elliptic-curves

Weierstrass form of elliptic curves is: $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$

The first four division polynomials equations are:
      $ψ_0=0$ 
       $ψ_1=1$ 
       $ψ_2=2y$ 
       $ψ_3=3x^4+6 A x^2+12 B x-A^2$ 
       $ψ_4=4 y(x^6+5 A x^4+20 B x^3-5 A^2  x^2-4 A B x-8 B^2-A^3 )$

Let  E  be the elliptic curve: $y^2=x^3+7$  (mod 79). Let point P=(9,5)  be the generator of E.
∴    A=0, B=7, x=9, y=5
Substituting, we get: 
      $ψ_0 = 0$ 
      $ψ_1 = 1$ 
      $ψ_2 = 2y=2×5=10$ 
      $ψ_3 = 3x^4+6 A x^2+12 B x-A^2=3×9^4+0+12×7×9-0 = 20439 = 57$ mod 79 
      $ψ_4 = 4×5(9^6+0+20×7×9^3-0-0-8×7^2-0) = 12662180 = 60$ mod 79

Square of $ψ_2=  ψ_2^2=10^2=100=21$ mod 79     . . . . . .  (1) 
Square of $ψ_3=  ψ_3^2=57^2=3249=10$ mod 79    . . . . . .  (2) 
Square of  $ψ_4=  ψ_4^2=60^2=3600=45$ mod 79   . . . . . .  (3)

Both Silverman’s “The Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves” (exercise 3.7 b) and Washington’s “Elliptic Curves – Number Theory and Cryptography” (Lemma 3.5) say:
      $ψ_m^2=m^2  x^{(m^2-1)}  +$ *lower degree terms* 
Applying this equation we get: 
      $ψ_0^2=0$ 
      $ψ_1^2=1^2×9^{(1^2-1)}=1×9^0=1+$ *lower degree terms* = 1 
      $ψ_2^2=2^2×9^{(2^2-1)}=4×9^{(4-1)}=4×9^3=2916=72$ *mod 79 + lower degree terms = $72+1 = 73$ mod 79* 
      $ψ_3^2=3^2×9^{(3^2-1)}=9×9^{(9-1)}=9×9^8=387420489=65$  *mod 79 + lower degree terms* = $65+73 = 138 = 59$ mod 79 
      $ψ_4^2=4^2×9^{(4^2-1)}=16×9^{(16-1)}=16×9^{15}=25$  *mod 79 + lower degree terms* $= 25+59 = 84 = 5$ mod 79 
Above 3 results do not match (1),(2),(3).

I know I am making some silly mistake somewhere, but could not figure out where. Can someone help find the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is about the elliptic curve $\, y^2 = x^3 + 7\,$
with point $\,(9, 5)\,$ over modulus $79$ and its division
polynomials. Your calculations are correct for $\psi_n$ and
its square modulo $79$. However your attempt to use

> $ψ_m^2=m^2  x^{(m^2-1)}  +$ *lower degree terms*

was flawed because you did not use the correct *lower degree
terms*. For the short elliptic curve $\, y^2 = x^3 + B\,$
the complete formulas are

\begin{eqnarray}
\psi_1^2 &=& 1, \\
\psi_2^2 &=& 4x^3  + 4B, \\
\psi_3^2 &=& 9x^8 + 72Bx^5 + 144B^2x^2, \\
\psi_4^2 &=& 16x^{15} + 656Bx^{12} + 6784B^2x^9 + 1024B^3x^6 - 4096B^4x^3 + 1024B^5 \end{eqnarray}
where we have replaced $\,y^2\,$ when it appears by
$\, x^3 + B.\,$ For example,
$$ \psi_2^2 = (2y)^2 = 4(y^2) = 4(x^3 + B) = 4x^3 + 4B. $$
When you substitute the values of $x=9$ and $B=7$ you get the correct results.

For example, $\,\psi_2^2 = 4\times 9^3 +4\times 7 = 2944 = 21 \pmod{79}.$

Comment: Did you ask sage to obtain $\psi_4^2$?

Comment: @reuns No, I used very simple code. For example, using `Wolfram Mathematica` I used `Z[4] = Expand[4*y*(x^6 + 5*A*x^4 + 20*B*x^3 - 5*A^2*x^2 - 4*A*B*x - 8*B^2 - A^3)];` and then `(Z[4]^2//Expand)/.{A -> 0, y^2 -> x^3 + B}//Expand` but I could have easily used `PARI/GP` to do the equivalent.

Comment: @Somos, thanks. What exactly is the flaw? And how did you arrive at the complete formulas from the equation referenced in the two books? (I am not familiar with nor have access to Sage, Mathematica, or anything.)

Comment: @Somos, also there is no B in that equation. How did it show up in your complete formulas?